# Is there a way to calculate f''(x)=0 in java?

Tags: java, calculation, polynomials, derivative

I need to know if there's a way to find f''(x)  = 0 in Java. I need this to calculate the inflection point of a "random" function. I've done research, but I wasn't able to find a correct answer (I can't calculate this in other languages like Python etc. I need to find a solution in Java). Any idea?

For now, I only have f''(x), but I don't know where to start to find f''(x)=0

```java
double[] x = { 0, -0.839, 1.33, -1.148, -1.0338, -0.8989 };
double[] y = { -2, 0, -0.81, 2.152, 1.24267, 0.342398 }; // test
double[] root;
PolynomialRegression regression = new PolynomialRegression(x, y, 3);
Function f = new Function(regression.toString());
Derivative deriv = new Derivative(f);
Function derive = deriv.findDerivative(f);
Derivative derivSeconde = new Derivative(derive);

System.out.println("Derivative is "+deriv.findDerivative(f).f);
System.out.println(regression.toString());
System.out.println("Second derivative is "+derivSeconde.findDerivative(derive).f);
```

Output:

```
Derivative is -3.0045962x^2+4.0051484x+0.0028687536
-1.0015320813678574x^3+2.002574163543064x^2+0.002868753687649257x+-1.9999326254109058
Second derivative is -6.0091925x+4.0051484
```

Comment: You have a convenient example here where the second derivative a linear function. Will that always be the case for you? Finding the root of a linear function is not a big deal.

Comment: No ... the fact is : I receive random data during 1 minute (second represent the x abscises) and with these data I need to find a function , so i use the polynomial regression method, next i find the derivative and next the second derivative.. so the function depend on the data that I receive) (Sorry for my English)

Comment: What `x` and `y` are wouldn't really matter (well it changes the result, but not how hard it would be to compute), but it matters that you fit a 3rd order polynomial through it (which implies that the second derivative is linear .. or constant but that's fine too)